# Footer Columns Size

Tags: add-theme-support

I hardly understand WordPress at all.  Am using the Generate Press theme.  Everything was correct but for some reason the image of my Facebook link in the left column of my footers no longer shows the right hand portion of the image, like the margins are set too small perhaps.  How do I reset it so the whole image shows and fills the column width like it used to?  (I have UpDraft backup but don't know how to use it to restore to a previous setting.  Would that solve the problem and, if so, how do I restore using UpDraft?)

Comment: It will be helpful if you could provide us the site URL.

Comment: I think I got it fixed.  Site is www.yeswolfcopywriters.com

Comment: Yes. Looks like it is fixed

Answer (score 1):

How to Restore using UpDraft is quite easy and you can follow this instruction carefully. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64S4S92v_0Q